# No-longer-ignored tag displays as ignored

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

I have a tag that is displaying in question lists in faded form as if it is one of my ignored tags, but it isn't.

I had it as one of my ignored tags for quite a while, but as I started using the app recently I "unignored" it some weeks ago.

The hover card shows a silver star like all of the other non-favorite, non-ignored tag, and the tag does not appear in the list of ignored tags.

So, I can only conclude that this is a bug. Perhaps some bit of data got left over when I removed the tag from my ignore list.

If it matters, the tag is [trello](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have `tag:trello*` in your ignored list.

Comment: It may say so in the database, but the UI is lying. Hang on; I'll add some screen shots.

Comment: Check your preferences page.

Comment: Aww. sonuva...Okay. The list of ignored tags in the sidebar has an overflow menu that is very hard to see. It turns out that I have many more ignored tags than I thought. So not a bug, but not great UI.